# Regex - accept characters from basic latin execept one

Tags: regex

I have a javascript reg ex that accepts the Basic Latin character set

`^[\u0000-~]+$`

But I also need to not accept the dollar sign ($)

I was thinking

`^[^$][\u0000-~]+$`

Is this possible?

https://regex101.com/r/tw584q/1

Comment: Just remove the `$` manually before checking or split your range into two.

Comment: Should it fail, if there's a $-sign? Or match up to the $-sign? Or replace the $-sign?

Comment: Are you sure you want to include \u000 through \u009f? Those are control codes, not latin characters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to validate input, you can split the range around `$` which should be `\u0024`

```
^[\u0000-\u0023\u0025-\u007e]+$
```

And for the record, `^[^$][\u0000-~]+$` would only ensure that the *first* character wasn’t a dollar sign.

Comment: What if... and I know this is in addition to my question... that instead of just the $ symbol, it was a specific string of ```$123``` I needed to exclude?

Comment: Then just check for it manually. Regex is not the answer to everything!

Comment: @lunchboxbill See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word